# Unexpected behavior while creating, writing and reading a Random Access File in C

Tags: c, random-access

I have been dealing with a problem with 3 programs from this book: [C How to Program - Deitel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136123562) They are related to the chapter 11 managing Files (Sequential and random access Files) in my studying method I like to test the example programs before I head the exercises, and I couldn't make work the 3 examples of the random access files (creating, reading and writing) I have got three unexpected behaviors. let me show:

- First I run the random access file creator, nothing seems weird and I get the finish message.
  [image]
- Second I compile the writing random access values file, then enter the values, nothing seems weird.
  [image: Entering values]
- Third I want to use the hare strategy and read the .dat file with notepad to see if the data got saved properly. And surprise some garbage is showed. And i thought well, maybe the double representation doesn't match with the reading program (notepad). So i moved to the fourth step.

[image: Reading File notepad]

- Fourth I compile the reading random access files program. and surprise the data showed isn't what I entered.

  [image: results didn't match]

I didn't want to post this question here cause I know there are more important questions, and more interesting but i can't find what I did wrong, and I have been looking for some time and I finally decided to ask the experts. I leave you the SC below (Thanks!):

```
/*To create the file*/
#include <stdio.h>

struct clientsData{
    int account;
    char lastname[ 30 ], name[ 30 ];
    double balance;
};

int main(void)
{
    int i; 
    struct clientsData client = { 0, "", "", 0.0 };
    FILE *cfPtr;


    if( ( cfPtr = fopen( "clients.dat", "wb" ) ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "File couldn't be opened. " );
    }
    else{
        printf( "Generating\n" );
        for ( i = 1; i <= 10000; i++ ){
            printf( "-" );
            fwrite( &client, sizeof( struct clientsData ), 1, cfPtr );
        }
            fclose( cfPtr );
    }
    printf( "\nFile succesfully created\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
/* To write the file */
#include <stdio.h>

struct clientsData{
    int account;
    char lastname[ 30 ], name[ 30 ];
    double balance;
};

int main(void)
{
    FILE *cfPtr;

    struct clientsData client = { 0, "", "", 0.0 };

    if( ( cfPtr = fopen( "clients.dat", "rb+" ) ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "File couldn't be opened. " );
    }
    else{
        printf( "Enter account number"" ( 1 to 10000, 0 to end the input )\n?" );
        scanf( "%d", &client.account );

        while( client.account != 0 ){
            printf( "Enter the lastname, firstname and the balance\n?" );
            fscanf( stdin, "%s%s%lf", client.lastname, client.name, &client.balance );
            fseek( cfPtr, ( client.account - 1 ) * sizeof( struct clientsData ), SEEK_SET );
            fwrite( &client, sizeof( struct clientsData ), 1, cfPtr );
            printf( "Enter account number\n?" );
            scanf( "%d", &client.account );
        }
        fclose( cfPtr );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
/*To read the File*/
#include <stdio.h>

struct clientsData{
    int account;
    char lastname[ 30 ], name[ 30 ];
    double balance;
};

int main(void)
{
    FILE *cfPtr;

    struct clientsData client = { 0, "", "", 0.0 };

    if( ( cfPtr = fopen( "clients.dat", "rb" ) ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "File couldn't be opened. " );
    }
    else{
        printf( "%-6s%-16s%-11s%10s\n", "Acct", "Lastname", "Firstname", "Balance" );

        while( !feof( cfPtr ) ){
            fread( &client, sizeof( struct clientsData ), 1, cfPtr );

            if( client.account != 0 ){
                printf( "%-6d%-16s%-11s%10.2f\n", &client.account, client.lastname, client.name, &client.balance );
            }
        }
        fclose( cfPtr );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"And i thought well, maybe the double representation doesn't match with the reading program (notepad)."* This is correct, just to clear that up.  The double is being stored in 64-bit IEEE Floating Point format, which is not (easily) readable by humans.  (And certainly not once interpreted as text.)

Comment: @DanielFischer That's not the problem; he's writing the entire struct value as a distinct record to disk, and reading it back the same way.  The data file format will be dependent on the compiler used, but other than that there are no problems with this approach.

Comment: @cdhowie Yeah, stopped reading at "notepad" ;)

Comment: True, there are better tools, and it would be more constructive to suggest one. Nothing was wrong with a cursory look via Notepad. BTW, it provided some useful information. Overall, well asked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like everything is saved correctly. But you print pointers instead of values here:

```
printf( "%-6d%-16s%-11s%10.2f\n", &client.account, client.lastname, client.name, &client.balance );
```

Should it be like this?

```
printf( "%-6d%-16s%-11s%10.2f\n", client.account, client.lastname, client.name, client.balance );
```

Comment: I concur :) Gah, you beat me by 10 seconds!

Comment: :) @Alberto Bonsanto, I don't mind if you accept QuasarDonkey's answer.

Comment: @QuasarDonkey the other alternative was using the arrow operator :P

Comment: I don't think so. `client` is defined as an instance of `struct clientsData`, not a pointer. You couldn't use the arrow operator here.

Comment: Ah wait, I see. You mean: `&client->account`

Answer (score 1):

This line in the file reader is wrong:

```
printf( "%-6d%-16s%-11s%10.2f\n", &client.account, client.lastname, client.name, &client.balance );
```

As it stands, you're printing addresses (pointers) to the account and balance variables, instead of the values of those variables.

It should read:

```
printf( "%-6d%-16s%-11s%10.2f\n", client.account, client.lastname, client.name, client.balance );
```

**Useful tip:** I found this error by enabling *compiler warnings*. `gcc` outputted these warnings:

```
reader.c:26:28: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
reader.c:26:28: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 5 has type 'double *' [-Wformat]
```

It would be a very good idea to find out how to enable these warnings in your compiler / IDE, as they will save you a lot of time with these kinds of problems.